# Correct way how to get and show data from specific JSON from API

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api, vue.js

I use the third-party API.
In request, I should add what fields I want to get. For example:

```
axios.get("APIURL", {
    params: {
      fields: ["username", "phone", ...etc]
    }
  })
```

And I get a response in this format:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "username": {
            "id": 17,
            "data": "JohnDoe",
            "created_at": "2019-05-09 15:52:23"
         }
    },
    {
         "phone": {
             "id": 2,
             "data": "+123456789",
             "created_at": "2019-05-08 17:31:52"
         }
    }]
}
```

I need to prepare an object with username, phone ...etc for showing in vuetify table. I do next:

```
response => {
      this.userInfo = {
        username: response.data.data[0].username.data,
        phone: response.data.data[1].phone.data
      };
    }
```

And in my view, it looks ugly. So, I have two questions:

1) How to get data from JSON? I need to show username, phone, email, address and more fields in vuetify table.

2)  Exist case where is some of the fields is undefined. For example, If got username, phone, address, but email is undefined. In my current code, I get error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Thank for help.

Comment: 1. You seem to do this correctly already. 2. Do some error checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the function that you can use to retrieve data that you need from the response:

```
function getData(data) {
  const out = {};

  data.forEach((items) => {
    Object.keys(items).forEach((key) => {
      out[key] = items[key].data;
    });
  });

  return out;
}
this.userInfo = getData(response.data.data) //usage of function
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative could be to simplify the object during parsing and reduce the resulting array to object :

```js
var json = '{"data":[{"username":{"id":17,"data":"JohnDoe","created_at":"2019-05-09 15:52:23"}},{"phone":{"id":2,"data":"+123456789","created_at":"2019-05-08 17:31:52"}}]}'

var arr = JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => v.data || v)

var obj = arr.reduce((o, v) => Object.assign(o, v), {})

console.log(obj)
console.log(arr)
```

or, without reduce :

```js
var obj = {}, json = '{"data":[{"username":{"id":17,"data":"JohnDoe","created_at":"2019-05-09 15:52:23"}},{"phone":{"id":2,"data":"+123456789","created_at":"2019-05-08 17:31:52"}}]}'

JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => v.data && k ? (obj[k] = v.data) : v)

console.log(obj)
```